# jQuery ui ReSizable with scroll bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to have a resizable on a div, but the resizer handle is always contained within the div can I have it where scrollbars end.

[image: demo]

/////////// Edit ///////////

I have achieved it with jScrollPane but after using jScroll I am unable to resize horizontally.
[demo http://i53.tinypic.com/906rk9.png](http://i53.tinypic.com/906rk9.png)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It should work, if you put a wrapper around the element to be resized, and make this wrapper resizable.

I was playing around with that idea and this result seems to work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".resizable")
  .wrap('<div/>')
    .css({'overflow':'hidden'})
      .parent()
        .css({'display':'inline-block',
              'overflow':'hidden',
              'height':function(){return $('.resizable',this).height();},
              'width':  function(){return $('.resizable',this).width();},
              'paddingBottom':'12px',
              'paddingRight':'12px'

             }).resizable()
                .find('.resizable')
                  .css({overflow:'auto',
                        width:'100%',
                        height:'100%'});
});
</script>
```

[Test with jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ka7P2/2/)

Comment: GOD BLESS YOU FOR SAVING MY TIME ON THIS :)

Answer (score 4):

jQuery UI team considers scrollable resizable div as a bad design. So it is "won't fix feature:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9119
Workaround as Dr.Molle already stated - resizable wrapper for scrollable div.

Answer (score 0):

Check option http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-alsoResize

This works for me

```
 $(".responsive-table th").resizable({
                handles: "e",
                containment: 'document',
                alsoResize: ".responsive-table table"
            });
```