# Jquery-ui resizable on a scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Im trying to have resizable/draggable objects contained inside a div with overflow : auto. (so that the objects stay on page like div and scroll up and down with the div)

To do that, I must set the position of the item to relative; unfortunately that will affect things when I resize because the resizing affects all previous objects.

**HERE IS A SAMPLE I MADE FOR TESTING:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        .dropZone {

            width: 750px;
            height: 750px;
            padding: 0;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin: 0;
            background: #aaa;
        }
        .forCanvas {
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            overflow: hidden;
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            background: white;
            border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .block {
            width: 80px;
            height: 60px;
            background: #d9d9d9;
            box-sizing:border-box;
            position: relative;
            align-content: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .block h3 {
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 15px;
                background: #d9d9d9;
                border: none;
                position: absolute;
            }

    </style>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="forCanvas" >
        <div class='block'><h3>Object1</h3></div>
        <div class='block'><h3>Object2</h3></div>
        <div class='block'><h3>Object3</h3></div>
        <div  class="dropZone ">
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>

            $(function(){

                $(".block") 
                    .draggable()
                    .resizable();   
            });


        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**You also need to have the jquery-ui.css to see the resizing handles:**

[This is the link to download the jquery zip that has the jquery.css file](https://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.12.1.zip)

I know that setting the .block position to absolute will fix the resizing problem, but they won't stay on div when I scroll.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery ui ReSizable with scroll bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858460/jquery-ui-resizable-with-scroll-bars)

Comment: How? I read that question before... He tries to add scrollbars inside the Resizable div... @yash